# Can I lock fields on Cognito Forms once they've been completed

Tags: cognito-forms

I've got a form that we require clients to fill in to book our services. We had an issue recently where a client changed the price for our service. Is it possible to lock some fields when they've been completed by us?

Comment: Hi! What field type are you using to display your prices? If they're in a Price field or a Choice field, your clients shouldn't be able to change them.